# Camera not working while shooting long distance

Tags: lens, nikon, focus

I have a nikon 3200 and lately I have observed that it does not allow me to take any photos if the lens is not zoomed. It doesnt even focus or take any picture even when I click the button. I checked the lens and it does the same in both A and M.

Comment: What lens? (Make, focal length range, aperture and any model designation.)

Comment: Some 18-55mm lenses have a lock button on the zoom ring. When locked, the lens is switched off and the camera does not take any pictures.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way for a zoom lens, not to be "zoomed".

What you probably have is a lock position. That is to shorten the lens a bit for storage and transportation.

Press the button and move the ring.

Take some minutes to read the manual of the camera.